# Android's "onActivityResult" mechanism won't work

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a big and frustrating problem with a simple application.
I have two Activities - A and B. Activity A opens activity B on a button click. Activity B has two "ends": If user clicks B.Back if just finish and goes back to A, if user clicks B.OK button, activity B is finished but before that it sets result "OK" so activity A can be closed too.

This is the pseudo code for A:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //some code...
                startAct(data);
            }
        });

private void startAct(Intent inte) {
        startActivityForResult(inte, -999);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        System.out.println(resultCode);

        if(requestCode != -999)
            return;

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            finish();
    }
```

Activity B does like this:

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //some other code...
                    finishOK();
                }
            });

private void finishOK() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
        finish();
    }
```

The problem is that this won't work - when i press the "btnOK" B should finish, A should "catch" the result and finish too, but it simply won't happen. What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a non-negative `requestCode`. If the `requestCode` is negative then `startActivityForResult` is the same as `startActivity`. See official document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: Oh God, there's my luck! I picked any number just to make it different and i pick the wrong one out of.... zillion of them :) Thanks, this works!